# Allow all text except <br /> tags

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have a blockquote in my application that allows some html elements for example "br /" tags tags. However the rest of the blockquote should accept html elements as normal text. for example,
< something > (with no spaces is fine) however < something (with no space does not work). I need to make this blockquote work as normal text except for br / tags. any ideas?

within the blockquote i am using

```
 <span ng-bind-html="text" | TextToHtmlSafe">
```

and in the back end i am sanitizing the string using:

```
_allowedTags = new List<string> {"br"};

var replacedHtml = Regex.Replace(html,
            @"</?(\w+)[^>]*>",
            me => AllowedTags.Any(s => s.Equals(me.Groups[1].Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                ? me.Value
                : HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(me.Value), RegexOptions.Singleline);

        return replacedHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you allow any other code (such as bbcode)?

If so, you could just replace all `<br />` tags with something like `[br]`, encode the html, and then replace all `[br]` tags back to `<br />`.

Something like the following:

```
var html = "some html<br />with breaks and <b>bolds</b>";
var encode = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html.Replace("<br />", "[br]")).Replace("[br]", "<br />");
```

The `encode` variable should then escape the bold tags while leaving the break intact.

Comment: anything within < > tags escapes ok. for example <b> <somethingelse> will show as plain text. it only breaks when I have <something with no closing tag ie <something will not show on the html client side screen however < something will show correctly